# How to have two single choice list on alert dialog?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-alertdialog

I need to implement two single choice list on an alert dialog. The two single choice items can be seen in the first picture. Once you clicked on the button , it will show a list of item(second picture). My question is how do I implement two single choice list item on an alert dialog? Thanks! 
[image]

[image]

picture is adopted and a screenshots from VirtualGuitar+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a layout with two spinners in horizontal linear layout.
Then make alert dialog with your layout xml like this

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builderVal=new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builderVal.setTitle("Title here") ;
        View holder=View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.spinners, null);
        builderVal.setView(holder);
       Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) holder.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
       //implement spinner logic
        builderVal.setPositiveButton("Okay",null);
        builderVal.show();
```

spinners.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"></Spinner>
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"></Spinner>

</LinearLayout>
```